# Trying to Link domain with Elastic Beanstalk app

Tags: dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to link my godaddy domain with my Elastic Beanstalk app, I did everything in this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLrE3eGHAR4 although I don't know its right or wrong. I also tried few other things but its not working. Also let me know if there are few other steps that I need to do which are not mentioned in the video.

Thanks in advance

To help you guys more I will add more information,
this is what I did so far,

1. Associated an Elastic IP address with my running instance.
2. Created a Hosted Zone and again that created a new Record set for www. and added my Elastic IP address in values.
3. I updated the NS from the hosted zone into my Nameservers and clicked save.

basically did everything as it was shown in the video.

I know it shows it takes 1 hour to 48 hours to propagate changes over the internet, but it is done maximum within 1 hour if everything is done right.

I hope this information helps.

Comment: This video is correct. It requires some time to make it valid.

Comment: what do u mean by make it valid ?

Comment: Need time to take effect.

Comment: If you use a Domain Hosted by a Third Party (such as GoDaddy), you just need to add a CName(Alias) record in GoDaddy's DNS Zone File and point it to your EB URL.

Otherwise, If you want to use a Domain Hosted by Amazon Route 53, you need follow the video to set up route 53 nameserver in GoDaddy.

Comment: I followed the video exactly but its not working, in the first option you mentioned, for which CName record in GoDaddy's DNS Zone File should I point my EB URL ?

Comment: I have record a video to set up a CNAME record in GoDaddy and point it to EB URL.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rwBOrowFx4

Answer (score 2):

If you need assign to beanstalk environment custom domain name, you need to create CNAME record in your DNS and point it on elastic beanstalk environment hostname.

Useful reading: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html
Same question here: [How to link godaddy domain with AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602232/how-to-link-godaddy-domain-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk-environment)

Comment: in CNAME record www should point to mysite.elasticbeanstalk.com ?

Comment: Yes, use mysite.elasticbeanstalk.com