# How to deploy a Ruby on Rails project to Amazon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

I have developed rails application, which I now want to deploy to an Amazon server. How can I do this?
Also I have registered domain name from godaddy.

Comment: What happened when you typed your question into google? :) When you then read the tutorials that were shown - what was missing from them that you weren't able to understand? When you tried it using your own project - what errors did you get that we can help you with?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do so is to have your application stored on a Git repository, [Github](http://github.com) for example. Then on your Amazon machine, clone your repo and you will have all your file on the cloud (almost) ready to use. Take a look at [this documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html) from Amazon for more infos.

For your domain, you must create a redirection to your Amazon machine IP. Here is [a link you should see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602232/how-to-link-godaddy-domain-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk-environment).