# AWS Route53 and GoDaddy: subdomains

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have domain on GoDaddy. I'm going to route (migrate DNS service) from GoDaddy to Route 53 like in following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38225802/3399047

In next step, I want to use subdomains for this domain.

**Where should I create subdomains?**

1. Create subdomains on GoDaddy and migrate them also to GoDaddy,
2. Create subdomains as A records for migrated domain on AWS Route 53?

(On AWS I will use domain and few subdomains as well)

*Bonus Question:*

After DNS migration to AWS, can I still use email account on GoDaddy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you move your DNS management from GoDaddy to AWS, you will no longer have the option of managing any DNS settings like your subdomains on GoDaddy. Subdomains are DNS records and they have to be configured at your DNS service, which will be Route53 after you make this change.

I don't think you will be able to use GoDaddy email any longer, but you might want to reach out to GoDaddy support for confirmation.

If you currently like GoDaddy and depend on some of their services for things like email, I would recommend checking first to verify that you need to move your DNS to Route53. If you just want to create some A records and CNAME records that point to your AWS resources you probably don't need to migrate to Route53.