# Domain name web alias does not take into the count urn part

Tags: url, redirect, dns, alias, urn

I have a small problem with domain names and dns configs.
There are two domains: `application12345.com` domain and `example.com`.
I want to show my application on domain `example.com`.

I try to create an alias 
`example.com` TO `application12345.com`.

I made

```
www.example.com 'CNAME' application12345.com
example.com 'Web alias' application12345.com
```

So `example.com` gets `application12345.com` index page.
If I click the link than content changes, but URN part is always the same.

Could you help me please? What should I do to show urn changes on `example.com` domain ?

P.S. Finally you can test it here:

> http://cryptoflick.fr/
>   http://prod-env.uy7cvnaywj.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/

Comment: I think you just need a redirect from your elastic-beanstalk to your domain name... might be a duplicate of this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602232/how-to-link-godaddy-domain-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk-environment

Comment: Some formatting

Answer (score 0):

My final solution which works

1. cryptoflick.fr web forward http://cryptoflick.fr
2. www.cryptoflick.com CNAME prod-env.uy7cvnaywj.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com
3. *.cryptoflick.com CNAME prod-env.uy7cvnaywj.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com