# Using parked GoDaddy domain on Amazon Route 53 - import zone file failed

Tags: dns, amazon-route53, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to use my parked GoDaddy domain name with AWS Elastic Beanstalk and followed as the answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602232/how-to-link-godaddy-domain-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk-environment) . I had a problem at step 4. I imported a zone file for windows from GoDaddy and when I imported it returned me a parsing error at PARKED. My import file looks like this:

```
; SOA Record
***.com.    600 IN  SOA ***.***.com.    dns.***.net (
                --------
                -----
                ----
                -----
                ---
                )

; A Records
@   600 IN  A   >>++PARKED1++<<

; CNAME Records
_domainconnect  3600    IN  CNAME   ***.**.****.com
www 3600    IN  CNAME   @
ftp 3600    IN  CNAME   @

; NS Records
@   3600    IN  NS  ***.****.com
@   3600    IN  NS  ***.****.com
```

I read AWS documentation on [migrating DNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/migrate-dns-domain-inactive.html) but it only says to just import. So what should I change in the settings or the import file?

Comment: The string `>>++PARKED1++<<` is an invalid target for an A record, it must be an IP address.

Comment: What IP address should I add? The IP of my EB app?

Comment: You should ask `AWS Elastic Beanstalk` support. You do not really need to import this zone file, since it's created for a parked domain at `GoDaddy`. Just ask them what records you need to add or ask `Google`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the IP address of your AWS Elasatic Beanstalk app. The A record is where your domain is pointing.

A Records point to IP addresses

CNAME points to another domain.

[Simple A Record vs CNAME explanation](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/differences-between-a-cname-alias-url/)

Comment: Where should I look up the IP address of my EB environment? I can't find it anywhere. I just added the URL of the environment in the A Records and it worked fine.

Comment: You sure you did not enter a CNAME? A record should only accept an IP address as the destination.