# GoDaddy domain in AWS with SSL for Wordpress application Issue

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Currently, I am working on a Wordpress application and I am using AWS hosting. My domain is in GoDaddy.com and I have deployed the application in elastic beanstalk. I have created load balancer and also I need to run the application through HTTPS.
I have done my research and I think I found the right way, but it's not working for HTTPS. when I browse on HTTP on port 80, it runs well. Now I am helpless.
Here's what I have done so far: 
1)   I created a hosted zone on AWS Route 53 for the domain named "example.com". There are two records are created, NS and SOA.
2)   Then, in GoDaddy, I added NS records from AWS as Custom Nameservers.

3)   After that, I created A record for the domain in the AWS hosted zone, set ALIAS targeted to the Load Balancer of the Elastic Beanstalk environment.

 
4)   Then, I changed the SITE URL from the wp_options table the wordpress application database.


After doing up to this, my application was running in HTTP. But as I want to change it to HTTPS. So,

1)   I requested a certificate from AWS Certificate Manager and created CNAME (provided by ACM after requesting certificate) record in the hosted zone.

2)   After the certificate is issued, I edited the listener from `EC2 >> Load Balancer >> Listener` and changed the protocol from HTTP to HTTPS and also allowed port on Security groups. 

3)   Also, I changed, the SITE URL from WordPress database and changed it from "http://example.com" to "https://example.com" but it was not working. 

4)   So I went to `Elastic Beanstalk >> Configuration >> Load Balancer` and added listener. After the environment is saved and restarted, still, the site was not running on HTTPS [ HTTP 408 ERROR IS SHOWN ]. But if I change SITE URL to "http://example.com", it works

I have found a solution, which says to use RedirectURL and set it to server config but I don't want to do that.

I also found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602232/how-to-link-godaddy-domain-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk-environment) which suggest to Export Zone File and import it to AWS hosted zone. But whenever I click Export Zone File(Unix), the file downloaded is shown empty. I tried this for other accounts, still, this problem exists. So I did not do that.

Sorry for the long story, but I really need this help.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue.

In my load balancer port configuration, I previously set load Balancer port 443 and instance 443. here what I need to do is to call the load balancer on port 443 and backend make the backend call on port 80 and enable https on WordPress.

So I kept load balancer port 443 and changed the instance port to 80. After that, on the browser, there was `too many redirects` error shown. So then what I needed to do is that add `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on'` on wp-config. And then everything was running smoothly.

[image]

I hope this will help if some