# AWS Wordpress HTTP to HTTPS Redirection Not Working

Tags: wordpress, https

I am having issue with Wordpress HTTP to HTTPS redirection. 
Currently I set up AWS EB application with Godaddy domain. I asked for help [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788173/godaddy-domain-in-aws-with-ssl-for-wordpress-application-issue/50832439#50832439). But currently I am having problem with redirection.

I have followed this solution. Found [here](https://www.davidmeents.com/add-ssl-ec2-wordpress-instance-use-https/).

*( **HTTP to HTTPS Redirection**)*


To redirect HTTP to HTTPS on wordpress application, I added the following lines at the top of the ***.htaccess***.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Also, added the following lines to **wp-config** just after MySQL setting.

```
/** force SSL on admin pages **/
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false){
    $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on'; 
}
```

Here is my full .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But its not working. when I go to http://example.com, its not redirecting to https://example.com, rather it is loading on http://example.com.

Please help.

## Edit

One thing I noticed that if I try http://www.example.com instead of http://example.com, it is redirecting to https://example.com, otherwise not. What is the reason for that?

Comment: have you set your home and site url in options table to https:// ?

Comment: @niklaz, yes I have already set home and site url to https://