# How to point www.domain.com to aws while domain.com point to somewhere else

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, cloudflare, amazon-route53

My domain is registered with godaddy. My `domain.com` is pointed to github, and I want `www.domain.com` point to aws. How to achieve it. Can I use route 53? And I want to add ssl to this `www.domain.com` from cloudflare .Please point me to right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it with just pointing cname without rout53

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following link to move your dns zone to Route 53,

[How to link godaddy domain with AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602232/how-to-link-godaddy-domain-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk-environment/38225802#38225802)